# Best way of getting a row result with out having to do several querys?

Tags: php

One of the fields coming from the db is separated by "," eg(1,2,3,4,5)
This is the code I'm using:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE phone=$user");

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $friends = $row['friends'];
     $data = $friends;
     $arr = explode(',', $data);
     $today = date("d F", strtotime($row['time']));
     $hour = date('g:i',
     strtotime($row['time']));
     if ($today < $row['time']) {
         $today;
     } else {
         $today = $hour;
     };
     for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
         $friend = array($data);
         foreach($friend as $value) {
             echo "      
 <div class='contacts_item sep_cont'>
          <img class='user_img' src='".$row['picture']."'>  
          <div class='contacts_title'>".$arr[$i]."<div class='time'>".$today."</div></div>
          <div>".$row['name']."</div>     </div>   ";
         }
     }
 }
```

Any advice?

Comment: What did you try so far? What exactly is the problem with that code?

Comment: There is no problem but I'll have to create the same amount of querys as the result of the for() and it looks very dirty.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want I think you can create a table with only the relation between  login and friends like

TABLE login_friends

```
    id    |    login_id   |   friend_id |
    1     |       1       |      2      |
    2     |       1       |      3      |
    3     |       2       |      3      |
```

Comment: That solution will work but this code is to build a instant messenger so that will work if the was only two people in each conversation but in some occasion they can be more than 20 and they all must match.

Comment: but you can add a column of conversation_id. And you need to explain more details of your question I answer with a big supose.